# Javascript google visualization api table undo sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-visualization

I have a google visualization Table

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

When a user clicks on the column headers it sorts based on that column. Is there a way to undo that sort and revert to the original order of the data? To be clear, I want to be able to sort, but I also want to be able to click somewhere and get the original order back. Is this possible?

Comment: You can sort your dataview and refresh table

Comment: @juvian - Sorry could you possibly elaborate on how I can sort the data view and refresh the table? I'm pretty new to this. Thanks

Comment: well, if you just need a button to revert to original order of data, just make a button that calls the function that draws the table so it gets reset

Answer (score 1):

Just redraw your Table to reset the sort order:

```
function redrawTable () {
    myTable.draw(data, options);
}
var btn = document.querySelector('#reset');
if (document.addEventListener) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', redrawTable);
}
else {
    btn.attachEvent('onclick', redrawTable);
}
```